# For what reasons can reader.readAsArrayBuffer fail?

Tags: javascript, promise, filereader

I am using the Filereader

```
const arrayBufferPromiseFromBlob = function (blob) {
    //argument must be blob or file Object
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            reject(error);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
};
```

sometimes it rejects (onerror), even though it was given a valid blob, what can be the reason this happens ?

Comment: what does the error say

Comment: Very large blob? or maybe you try to read a file that you don't have access to some file that have come from a drop event where you do `event.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the calling code using `arrayBufferPromiseFromBlob` , attach a `.catch()` to the promise and log the error.